# Deleting dataset in azure data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I want to delete the dataset inside my adfv2 which are not referenced with any pipeline.

I can go to each dataset and in view section I can see either the dataset is related or not and I can delete.

But I don't want to go to each dataset and perform above operation. Does anyone knows better way of doing it.

It might help many developer to clean their adf pipelines

Comment: Hi @amikm, per my experience, there isn't a better way to doing that. But you provide a good idea to improve Data Factory features, you can create a new feedback for this request.

Comment: Hi @amikm,  hope you're doing well. If you also agree with me, hope you can accept the answer as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @amikm, are you here?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, there isn't a better way to doing that. But you provide a good idea to improve Data Factory features.

I would suggest create a new [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback) for Data Factory. We can help vote it and product team could see it.

HTH.

Comment: I will add to the feedback section of the adfv2

Comment: Hi @amikm,  do you need us help you vote the feedback?

Comment: Feedback is created 
 https://feedback.azure.com/forums/270578-data-factory/suggestions/43886484-delete-dataset-which-is-not-related-to-any-pipelin